# Passing int type variable value from Content Page(aspx) to masterpage and usercontrols

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to pass variable from content page to master page and usercontrol in `asp.net webforms`

`MasterPage.aspx` being used by below content page.

```
Default.aspx
Aboutus.aspx
contactus.aspx
```

If i am not wrong then page execution happens as

```
Content Page
Master Page
User Control
```

for this reason i want to define variable let us say page_id in `default.aspx`, `About.aspx`, `contactus.aspx`...

So that I can get the value of page_id itself on content page as pass it to master page and user control if required.

I am not sure how can i pass a variable `page_id` value to another variable name also `page_id` in master page. I need to do this as I am not allowed to use any querystring or url routing value for page_Id

I need to pass variable not the value from any `text-box` IS IT POSSIBLE or i have to use a `hidden-field` for this

[image]

I need to pass value as show in image below.

Comment: Is the user control in the master page? Or in the aspx page? In essence you want to get a variable from the content page in the user control, both contained in the master page right?

Comment: All my userControls are on  the content pages `aspx`  and i need to value let us say page_id  to master page as well as user controls.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will want to work with `properties` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720435(v=vs.71).aspx

*Edited to reflect further information*

So if the user controls have:

```
public partial class _ascx1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int page_id { set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // The webcontrol does things here
       if(page_id > 0) { };
    }
}

public partial class _ascx2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int page_id { set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // The webcontrol does things here
       if(page_id > 0) { };
    }
}
```

The master page has the following:

```
public partial class _MyMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public int page_id { set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // My Master page stuff
       if(page_id > 0) {}; // DO stuff with page ID
    }
```

Then the content pages have something along the lines of:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ((_ascx1)Page.FindControl("ascx1_id")).page_id = 1;
     ((_ascx2)Page.FindControl("ascx2_id")).page_id = 1;

     ((_MyMaster)Page.Master).page_id = 1;
}
```

Then in the webcontrol and master page, you should be able to access `page_id` and do what you wish with it.

By setting the ID's in `Page_Init` of the content pages, it means that ID should be available in your `Page_Load` events of the Webcontrols and Master Page.

You ***could*** use a textbox / hidden field on the master page:

```
<asp:hiddenField id="hdnField" runat="server" value="0" />
```

Then in the content page set it:

```
((HiddenField)Page.Master.FindControl("hdnField")).value = "1";
```

And access it on the master page:
    int page_id = hdnField.value

Or Webcontrol:
    int page_id = int.Parse(((HiddenField)Page.Master.FindControl("hdnField")).value);

Comment: at RemarkLema, I mean to pass a variable value `int  Page_ID" defined in .aspx file and i want to pass it to _mp_page_id defined in master page

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker I see where you going, thanks for the additional info. I've edited the answer to reflect my thoughts. 2 ways, properties or a hidden control. Properties to my mind is a much neater way of passing stuff around, but if you need any interaction from the client side via JavaScript then you tend to need to work with hidden fields and hidden text boxes.